# How to reinstall ros-noetic on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, ros

I'm trying to reinstall my ros-noetic on Ubuntu 20.04. I have done
`sudo apt-get remove ros-*` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`
I think I have already removed all the previous ros.
now I'm following installation guide on [ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu), but always claims that:
"E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

For more detailed information please check this screenshot:

[image: check the screenshot of the terminal]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)